# Ротация в canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript

Как повернуть изображение в Canvas?

Знаю, что можно крутить холст, но создавать для каждой картинки новый холст - не вариант, ибо картинок очень много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/158495/

http://habrahabr.ru/post/104718/

Answer (score 0):

[Как повернуть только одно изображение в canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514256/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-canvas/514276#514276)

Здесь я ответил подробно. Если вкратце, то нужно перед тем, как делать трансформирование, крутить и тому подобные манипуляции с холстом нужно контекст предварительно сохранить командной

```
ctx.save();
```

После того, как отрисуем нужный фрагмент возвращаем старые настройки

```
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: вовсе не обязательно сохранять потом восстанавливать текущий контекст - если реализовать все основные афинные преобразования на плоскости в ручную то можно трансоформировать всё что рисуется на холсте не трогая координатную систему впринципе.