# Как повернуть только одно изображение в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, разработка-игр

Всем привет.

Пишу html5 платформер, так вот, встала задача вращать изображение героя, все это в canvas. Но при рендеринге вращаются и фон и и все остальные герои, каша одним словом.

Перерыл весь интернет в поиске решения проблемы, пробовал создавать новый контекст для каждого героя `this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");` но не помогло, прошу вашей помощи, заранее спасибо !)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Сохраняем настройки канваса до всяких манипуляций с ним
ctx.save();

// Сдвигаем все адресованные пиксели на указанные значения
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);

// Поворачиваем на `degrees` наш градус
ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);

// Рисуем повернутую картинку
ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.width/2);

// Восстанавливаем настройки на момент когда делали `ctx.save`
// то бишь до `ctx.translate` и `ctx.rotate`. Рисунок при этом сохраняется.
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло !)