# Поворот картинки canvas без искажения системы координат

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, разработка-игр, математика

Всем привет.

Такой вопрос, есть картинка, я её поворачиваю и вставляю в определенные координаты, однако при повороте допустим на 45 градусов `this.ctx.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);` система координат тоже поворачивается, и картинка попадает совсем в другое место canvas'a . Помогите пожалуйста это исправить ?

При увеличении x - >
[image: Действие при увеличении x]

Comment: Вам уже [ответили на этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514256/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-canvas), выполнять save перед действиями и restore после. Если что-то не получается, то хотя бы приведите достаточный код, где эта проблема воспроизводится.

Comment: Нет, это другой вопрос, дело в том что при повороте картинки поворачивается система координат, разумеется я могу её развернуть обратно путем restore() , но мне её перед этим нужно в правильном месте отрисовать .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам на примере подсказал, что нужно использовать трансформ. Все дело в работе метода rotate. Он крутит относительно верхнего левого угла.

Так что перед тем как крутить картинку нужно сместить координаты в центр предполагаемой картинки

Comment: Дело не в том  куда он крутит, а в том, что при увеличении x картинка двигается не вправо, а в бок см. http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/04/b8f4bdbebb5e9855bb45cf3caf6a5b5a.png

Comment: Так крутятся координаты канваса! :) и перед тем как менять координаты Вы должны восстановить настройки канваса, посчитать новые координаты,  повернуть и отрисовать. Так будет гораздо удобнее

Comment: Спасибо огромное !)